# ng test run fail with tsconfig path mapping

Tags: angular

I've configured `tsconfig.json` for path mapping to import like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "paths" : {
         "@enum/*": [
           "src/app/enum/*"
         ],
         "@util/*": [
           "src/app/util/*"
         ]
       }
    }
}
```

I've a class OrderService :

```
import {DateUtil} from "@util/date_util";
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class OrderService {

  //Some codes implement here

}
```

I write test case for class `OrderService` and run `ng test`, this issue occurs:

> **error TS2307: Cannot find module '@util/date_util'.**

Anyone can help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the paths property inside compiler options

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@enum/*": [
        "src/app/enum/*"
      ],
      "@util/*": [
        "src/app/util/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, that's mistake on my typing. Can you provide any solution for this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. no luck